# Ruby - adding negative float values

Tags: ruby, decimal, addition

I am new to Ruby, so I'll apologize for my ignorance first :)  I am finding a problem when totaling a customer's account.  Some of the amounts are negative with decimal places, and this is corrupting the total.  Here is some simple example code...

```
testnum = 0.00
puts "###Debug### testnum = #{testnum} (after  0.00)"
testnum += 5.00
puts "###Debug### testnum = #{testnum} (after  5.00)"
testnum += 3.33
puts "###Debug### testnum = #{testnum} (after  3.33)"
testnum += -1.00
puts "###Debug### testnum = #{testnum} (after -1.00)"
testnum += -2.22
puts "###Debug### testnum = #{testnum} (after -2.22)"
```

with the results...

```
###Debug### testnum = 0.0 (after  0.00)
###Debug### testnum = 5.0 (after  5.00)
###Debug### testnum = 8.33 (after  3.33)
###Debug### testnum = 7.33 (after -1.00)
###Debug### testnum = 5.109999999999999 (after -2.22)
```

So testnum is corrupted after adding -2.22, but adding -1.00 was fine.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colonel Panic is right about the reasoning and i dont want to repeat the same, additionally you can use round function. For eg:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > 5.109999999999999.round(2)
 => 5.11
```

since you are using only upto 2 deciaml digits this should be useful to you

Answer (score 2):

From http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

> Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2 add up to a nice round 0.3, and instead I get a weird result like 0.30000000000000004?
>
> Because internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point) that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> If you really need your results to add up exactly, especially when you work with money: use a special decimal datatype.

In Ruby, this is [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: Thanks very much.  I used .to_d to convert the amounts to BigDecimal before adding them and it worked fine.